# Ecommerce Cart & Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I'm facing problem that how to add multiples items in an array to send data to paypal i'm using following script for cart and paypal integration. When i add one item in my cart it's working fine but when i attempt to add multiple items it will add items in cart but it will send only last item to paypal for transaction. Here is live example for what i'm trying to explain http://anushn.hostingsiteforfree.com/ecommerce/index.php . 
 Any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
?>
<?php
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 1 (if user attempts to add something to the cart from the product page)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $wasFound = false;
    $i = 0;
    // If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
    if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) { 
        // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
        $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
    } else {
        // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $pid) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
                      $wasFound = true;
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop
           } // close foreach loop
           if ($wasFound == false) {
               array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
           }
           $total_quantity = count($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    }
    header("location: cart.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
<?php
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 2 (If user wants to remove an item from cart)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if(isset($_POST['item_to_remove']) && ($_POST['item_to_remove'] != ""))
{
    $key_to_remove = $_POST['item_to_remove'];
    if(count($_SESSION['cart_array']) <= 1)
    {
        unset($_SESSION['cart_array']);
    }
    else
    {
        unset($_SESSION['cart_array'][$key_to_remove]);
        sort($_SESSION['cart_array']);
    }
}
?>
<?php 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//       Section 3 (render the cart for the user to view)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$cart_output="";
$cart_total = "";
$pp_checkout_btn = "";
if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1)
{
    $cart_output = "<h2 align='center'>Your Shopping Cart Is Empty</h2>";
}
else
{

    // Start the For Each loop
    $i=0;
    foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item)
    {
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $product_name = $row['product_name'];
            $price = $row['price'];
            $detail = $row['details'];
            $cat = $row['category'];
            $sub_cat = $row['subcategory'];
            $cover = $row['cover_location'];
        }

        $total_item_price = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
        $total_item_price2 = number_format($total_item_price, 2);

        $cart_total = $total_item_price + $cart_total;



        // Create the product array variable
        $product_id_array .= "$item_id-".$each_item['quantity'].","; 

        $cart_output .= "<div class='cart_output'>";
        $cart_output .= "<h2>Cart Item $i</h2>";
        $cart_output .= "<img src=$cover width='100' height='100'><br/><br/>";
        $cart_output .= "Item Name : " . $product_name . "<br/>";
        $cart_output .= "Unit Price : $" . $price . "<br/>";
        $cart_output .= "Total : $" . $total_item_price2 . "<br/>";
        $cart_output .= "<br /><form action='cart.php' method='POST' name='' id =''>
        <input type='submit' name='deleteBtn"."$item_id' id='' value='Remove Item'>
        <input type='hidden' name='item_to_remove' id='' value='$i'>
        </form>
        ";
        $cart_output .= "</div>";
        $i++;
    }
    $cart_total = number_format($cart_total,2);

    //Start PayPal Checkout Button
    $POST_DATA = array(
    "METHOD"     => "BMCreateButton",
    "VERSION"    => "65.2",
    "PWD"        => "090078601",
    "USER"        => "mystore.yahoo.com",
    "SIGNATURE"    => "adadaadadada",
    "BUTTONCODE"=> "ENCRYPTED",
    "BUTTONTYPE"=> "BUYNOW",
    "BUTTONSUBTYPE" => "SERVICES",
    "BUTTONCOUNTRY" => "US",
    "BUYNOWTEXT" => "PAYNOW",
    "BUTTONIMAGE" => "REG",
    "BUTTONIMAGEURL" => "https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/btn/btn_pponly_142x27.png",
    "L_BUTTONVAR0" => "bussiness=mustafazahid43@yahoo.com",
    "L_BUTTONVAR1"  => "item_name=$product_name",
    "L_BUTTONVAR2"  => "amount=$price",
    "L_BUTTONVAR3"    => "custom=$product_id_array",
    "L_BUTTONVAR4" => "notify_url=http://yoursite.com/ecommerce/storescripts/my_ipn.php",
    "L_BUTTONVAR5" => "cancel_return=http://yoursite.com/ecommerce/paypal_cancel.php",
    "L_BUTTONVAR6" => "return=http://yoursite.com/ecommerce/checkout_complete.php",
    "L_BUTTONVAR7"  => "quantity=$each_item[quantity]",
    "L_BUTTONVAR8"  => "upload=0",
    );


  $context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
      'method'  => 'POST',
      'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
      'content' => http_build_query($POST_DATA),
      'timeout' => 10,
    ),
  ));
$response = file_get_contents("https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp/",true,$context);
parse_str($response, $output);
$button = str_replace("\\","",$output["WEBSITECODE"]);

} 
?>

<html>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="sub_container">
   <?php echo $cart_output; ?>  
   <br/>
   <br>
<?php echo $button;?>

 <div style="margin-top:20px; color:#CCC; float:right;"><b><?php if($cart_total != "") {echo "Total Shopping : $".$cart_total." USD";} ?></b></div>
  </div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

BMCreateButton is for a single item.  If you wanted to use PayPal's shopping cart you would need to create cart buttons instead of Buy Now buttons, and have a single button for each item.  Then you'd also have a separate View Cart button, but that cart would all be driven by PayPal.

It's really not what I'd recommend.  Since you already have your own shopping cart, all you need to do is send the data to PayPal.  You can do that very easily using the "[cart upload command](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/)" method, which is exactly what it's intended for.

You'll do exactly what you're doing here, but instead of building an NVP string and making an API call, you'll simply build an HTML form with hidden input variables.  You can refer to [PayPal's standard variable reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) for details on what you can include.

Even better would be to use the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/), since you are familiar with API calls.  Since you're working with PHP, I'd recommend taking a look at my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/).  It would make Express Checkout very quick and easy for you to integrate.

Comment: Is there any way to secure the html hidden variables ?

Comment: You could look into [Encrypted Payments](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/xcl/rec/ewp-intro-outside) or [Hosted Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/button-manager/integration-guide/NVP/ButtonMgrOverview/#id093VD0JE0Y4).

Comment: BMCreateButton is only way to create encrypted button on fly ? i don't want to host button on paypal site

Comment: Then yes, the button API would be your best bet.

Comment: I want to setup paypal integration like woo commerce have. Can you tell me what method they are using for paypal ?

Comment: WooCommerce has Payments Standard (cart upload method) built in by default.  I actually released [PayPal for WooCommerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/) a few months back that integrates Express Checkout and Payments Pro into WooCommerce, which is much better than Standard.

Comment: I am fully determined to use this with multiple items, as someone was able to get it working with PHP. I'm trying to do the same with ASP.net.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382987/paypal-encrypt-muti-item-custom-cart-dynamic-checkout-button-with-php?rq=1