# HTTP Post: getting encrypted Paypal multiple-item cart upload button

Tags: encryption, paypal, shopping-cart

I am having trouble using the [BMCreateButton](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMCreateButton_API_Operation_NVP/) of the Button Manager API to get a multiple-item cart uploaded.
Inside the paypal [documentation for the cart upload command](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/), the paragraph on "securing your button" implies that it should be possible to get encrypted buttons for all the functions listed above, including the cart upload form. And in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382987/paypal-encrypt-muti-item-custom-cart-dynamic-checkout-button-with-php?rq=1), someone states they have solved this with PHP, but having looked it up, it's not evident they use a simple HTTP Post, as it's got to do with a PHP class's internal workings.

So far, I am able to only view one item only, and when trying to use the multiple-item syntax (`item_name_1`, `item_name_2`...) it's showing no items at all with a total of `0.00`.

Here is my request code:

```cs
string requestContent =
  "METHOD=BMCreateButton" +
  "&VERSION=85.0" +
  "&USER=<user>" +
  "&PWD=<pwd>" +
  "&SIGNATURE=<sig>" +
  "&BUTTONCODE=ENCRYPTED" +
  "&BUTTONTYPE=BUYNOW" +
  "&BUTTONIMAGE=reg" +
  "&BUTTONCOUNTRY=US" +
  "&BUTTONSUBTYPE=PRODUCTS" +

  //"&L_BUTTONVAR1=cmd%3D_cart" + //having this in here definitely causes an error message to display
  "&L_BUTTONVAR1=button_subtype%3DPRODUCTS" +
  "&L_BUTTONVAR2=business%3Dbiz%40biz.com" +
  "&L_BUTTONVAR3=item_name_1%3DToaster" +
  "&L_BUTTONVAR4=amount_1%3D45.00" +
  "&L_BUTTONVAR5=quantity_1%3D1" +
  "&L_BUTTONVAR6=upload%3D1";
```

It doesn't work -I have asked the PayPal tech support and will post back here if I hear anything back from them on this topic.

Comment: Hi @Vasily Hall, any progress on the issue? I'm facing very similar challenge myself.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, I had lost this thread a long time ago!
Unfortunately, although it's not clearly documented in PayPal documents, this is indeed impossible to my knowledge. We had to go a completely different way and use one of their APIs to create the transactions, which my co-worker implemented when he took it over since I was having so much difficulty with it.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry to hear that. I hope I will figure out something simpler. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue and as there was no progress, I contacted PayPal support. [There is the answer](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Button-APIs/Cannot-create-ENCRYPTED-CART-UPLOAD-button-but-unsecured-works/m-p/1267689/):

There is quoted reply in case the link will die:

> It's not only with ENCRYPTED. If you try CLEARTEXT, the same error is thrown.
>
> Upload cart is a slightly different kind of button, that was never intended to be pre-built, and that's why this functionality doesn't exist in BMCreateButton. If you compare the Button Manager in the account and the API functionality - they have the same capabilities and, in both cases, the upload cart isn't there.
>
> Looking at the documentation, you will also notice the BUTTONTYPE=CART refers to Add to cart.
>
> It makes perfect sense to try to secure the upload cart code, but the best way will always be post-transaction consistency verification (with IPN).

So to sum this up, it is not possible to encrypt it, we can only detect tampering, e.g., with IPN.

In the reaction to my question, the PayPal moderator filed an issue to clarify this in the documentation.